# Amazon S3 SDK: Change filename on download?

Tags: php, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

Is this the correct way to generate a URL and change it's download name?

```
$s3 = new AmazonS3();
$opt =  array('response' => array('Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; "filename=newname.txt"'));
$url = $s3->get_object_url('bucket', 'file.txt', '5 minutes', $opt));
```

Apparently doesn't work with me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After several tests, apparently **get_object_url** requires **Content-Disposition** parameter to be in lower case.

Note that this is not the case for **create_object** which works case-insensitive.

So the working code for above is:

```
$opt =  array('response' => array('content-disposition' => 'attachment; "filename=newname.txt"'));
```